# first of 3 segments of UISegmentedControl to take half of width

Tags: ios, xcode, storyboard, uisegmentedcontrol

Through the storyboard, is there a way to setup my UISegmentedControl so that of the segments FIRST, SECOND, THIRD: FIRST always gets half of the with while SECOND and THIRD are proportioned by content size with respect to each other? I could do this easily if I could add UIViews inside my UISegmentedControl but I can't.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll have to do this programmatically as far as I know:

```
- (void)setWidth:(CGFloat)width forSegmentAtIndex:(NSUInteger)segment
```

It would result in something like

```
- (void)viewWillAppear;
{
    float firstWidth = self.view.frame.size.width / 2;
    [self.segmentedControl setWidth:firstWidth forSegmentAtIndex:0];
    // The others should resize automatically
}
```

I would suggest that you skip the segmented view entirely and do it with UIViews instead so you can use the full power of Auto Layouts. UISegmentedControl styling is a bit of a leftover from the days that there was only one screen size to deal with.

Answer (score 1):

**EDIT: This actually might not be the solution. There's no way to tell what the size of each segment is, at least using the storyboard.**

If the text on the UISegmentedControl is always going to be the same and you know what the size of the whole control is, the following should work:

Click on the UISegmentedControl in the Storyboard and go to the Size Inspector. From there, you can choose the width of each segment. You will have to do some simple math to calculate the widths for the first segment.

[image]